# Where does the silverlight 3 toolkit MSI put the DLL files?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

Just downloaded the [Silverlight 3 Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=20430) and executed the MSI file.

Now I need to reference the Microsoft.Windows.Controls.dll file but don't know where MSI unpacked it. Can't find it at C:\ or in C:\Program Files. **Where might it be?**

- ok, [this post](http://www.silverlightshow.net/news/The-Silverlight-Toolkit-grows-up-a-little-with-an-install-experience-.aspx) says that all the components should be in the toolbox, e.g. DockPanel, they are for Visual Studio 2008 Professional **but not for Visual Web Developer 2008 Express** (it has some controls but not DockPanel for instance)

## Answer:

Ok, **the answer is: reboot and restart everything** (until then Silverlight got a `AG_E_PARSER_BAD_TYPE` error, and brought down both Visual Studio versions and Firefox). After restarting everything, it works fine: the controls are automatically in the toolbox so you just have to drag them in, [no need referencing the dll anymore as in Silverlight 2](http://www.tanguay.info/web/index.php?pg=howtos&id=1).

Comment: It's probably better practice to answer your own question below, so that it can be properly voted on.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The July 2009 release of the Silverlight Toolkit added a "Open the welcome page" choice at the end of the MSI setup.

The path names for the July release are also slightly different, but using the Welcome page (a link is also added to the Start Menu), you'll always have a quick method to find 'em.

Checking that box will make sure that a page opens up with details about everything that's installed, including links to all the binaries, themes, the documentation, etc.

Also, since the controls are all referenced through the AssemblyFolderEx registry key, you can add a GAC-style reference in your C# or VB.NET project...

```
<Reference Include="System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit" />
```

And that will just work when built on a machine with the Silverlight SDK.

Hopefully it's a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

It didnt automatically add anything for me for Silverlight Beta 4 Toolkit and Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2.

I followed [these instructions](http://shawnoster.com/Blog/Adding-Silverlight-Toolkit-Controls-to-the-Visual-Studio-and-Blend-Toolbox). My toolkit bin was located :

```
 C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v4.0\Toolkit
```

In addition I had to select additional DLLs for additional toolkit items from those described in the article. I also had to check the checkbox to indicate I actually wanted those items.

There must be a better way! Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone was wondering, I was :-).

There is a start menu group named "Microsoft Silverlight 3 Toolkit March 2009" with all the relevant info. The toolkit assemblies can be found in "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v3.0\Toolkit\March 2009\Libraries"